# Accessing Frontmatter elements in grouped graphql query

Tags: graphql, gatsby, sharp

I am attempted to return the featuredImage from within the frontmatter of the latestpost in a category.

Here is the graphql query I have currently written:

```
query catList {
        allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
          group(field: frontmatter___themes, limit: 1) {
            fieldValue
            totalCount
            nodes {
              frontmatter {
                featuredImage {
                  childImageSharp {
                    fixed(width: 400, height: 400) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

The query returns exactly what I want in the graphql editor, however when I try to access the featuredImage in my components, I get an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'featuredImage' of undefined"

Here is the full code for the page and components:

```
const CatPage = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query themeList {
        allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
          group(field: frontmatter___themes, limit: 1) {
            fieldValue
            totalCount
            nodes {
              frontmatter {
                featuredImage {
                  childImageSharp {
                    fixed(width: 400, height: 400) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <Layout>
        <Gallery>
          {data.allMdx.group.map(theme => (
            <GalleryCard to={theme.fieldValue} title={theme.fieldValue}>
              <Img
                fixed={
                  theme.nodes.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fixed
                }
              />
            </GalleryCard>
          ))}
        </Gallery>
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
)
```

The goal here is to have the featured image from the most recent post with each category be the cover image for the category, but I am having difficulties getting the image to render!

Comment: Do all of the posts have frontmatter?

Comment: Yes, all of the MDX files in the whole project have frontmatter. I’m just testing with 3 files at the moment.